# Powershell - How to exclude the header from a table

Tags: powershell, datatables

I'm a complete beginner in any programming language, I'm trying to create a powershell script that will give me information on VM clusters like their name, version, ntp and syslog settings from a list of servers.

```
connect-viserver vcserver.xxx.com
$servers = get-content 'C:\users\xxx\Downloads\Servers.txt'
foreach ($server in $servers){get-cluster -vm $server | Select Name |Format-Table -AutoSize}
foreach ($cluster in $clusters) {Get-Cluster $cluster | Get-VMhost |select Name, Version, Build, @{N="NTP";E={Get-VMHostNtpServer $_}}, @{N="Syslog Server";E={(Get-AdvancedSetting -Entity $_ -Name "Syslog.global.loghost").value}}}
```

What I get back as 'clusters' is a table that looks like this:

```
Name      
----      
XXX



Name        
----        
YYY
```

So when the second part runs and its trying to give me back the info I get this error:

```
Get-Cluster : 7/23/2020 10:32:33 AM Get-Cluster     Cluster with name '----        ' was not found using the specified filter(s).   
At line:4 char:34
+ foreach ($cluster in $clusters) {Get-Cluster $cluster | Get-VMhost |s ...
+                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-Cluster], VimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Core_OutputHelper_WriteNotFoundError,VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Cmdlets.Commands.GetCluster
    enter code here

Get-Cluster : 7/23/2020 10:32:33 AM Get-Cluster     Cluster with name 'Name        ' was not found using the specified filter(s).   
At line:4 char:34
+ foreach ($cluster in $clusters) {Get-Cluster $cluster | Get-VMhost |s ...
+                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-Cluster], VimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Core_OutputHelper_WriteNotFoundError,VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Cmdlets.Commands.GetCluster
```

How can I tell it to only use the name XXX from the list of clusters instead of trying to use 'Name' and '---' as variables.

Hope this makes sense.

---

OK, now I changed the script to:

```
    foreach ($server in $servers){
get-cluster -vm $server | Select -ExpandProperty Name
}
foreach ($cluster in $clusters) {get-cluster $cluster | Get-VMhost |select Name, Version, Build, @{N="NTP";E={Get-VMHostNtpServer $_}}, @{N="Syslog Server";E={(Get-AdvancedSetting -Entity $_ -Name "Syslog.global.loghost").value}}}
```

But now I just get the list of clusters and then it stops, it never gives me the information I request from each cluster

Comment: `Select Property` displays an object, which includes its property name. `Select -Expand Property` displays only the property value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are wanting to display a collection's property values rather than the object itself. The `-ExpandProperty` parameter of `Select-Object` can do this.

```
$clusters = foreach ($server in $servers) {
    Get-Cluster -Vm $server | Select -ExpandProperty Name
}
foreach ($cluster in $clusters) {
    Get-Cluster $cluster | Get-VMhost |
        Select Name, Version, Build, @{N="NTP";E={Get-VMHostNtpServer $_}}, @{N="Syslog Server";E={(Get-AdvancedSetting -Entity $_ -Name "Syslog.global.loghost").value}}
}
```

It is not wise to pipe to `Format-*` commands if you are planning to process the result in future commands. The `Format-*` commands apply formatting and output a different object type than your original result. You cannot access the unformatted object's properties afterwards.

Comment: That fixed the format! Now I only see the Name, but somehow now the second part of the script is not doing anything. It stops after showing me the Cluster names.

Comment: You need to set `$clusters`. Should that be the output of the command I posted?

Comment: Yes it should. I tried doing an Out-File after the command you posted, but I only get the last line.

`foreach ($server in $servers){get-cluster -vm $server | Select -ExpandProperty Name | Out-File 'C:\users\xxx\Downloads\Clusters.txt'`

And I set $clusters as:
`$clusters = Get-Content C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\Clusters.txt`

Comment: You can just store it in a variable. I've made an update showing you how.